# Expectation of piecewise constant function

Tags: expected-value

Say I have a set $\mathcal{X}$ and a partition $A := (A_{1}, \dots, A_{M})$, i.e. subsets such that $\dot{\cup}_{i=1}^M A_{i} = \mathcal{X}$ and the $A_{i}$s are pairwise disjoint.
Say further I have a function $f: \mathcal{X} \to \mathcal{Y}$ that is piecewise constant on the cells of $A$, i.e.

$$
f (x) = \begin{cases}
f_{1} & x \in A_{1} \\
\dots \\
f_{M}  & x \in A_{M}
\end{cases}
$$

Consider now a random variable $X$ that is evenly distributed on $\mathcal{X}$, i.e. its probability density function is $p(x) = \varphi ~ ,\forall x$.

I am interested in expressing the expectation of $f(x)$ over $\mathcal{X}$ in terms of the function values $f_{1}, \dots, f_{m}$ at the cells of the partition.

Here's what I have so far but I am not sure it's correct. Mostly, I am unsure whether, in the last line, the individual summands should be having a weight factor that corresponds to the sizes of the cells.
$$
\begin{align}
 \mathbb{E}_{X}\left[ f(X) \right]  &= \int f(x) \varphi \, dx  \\
 &= \int_{A_{1}} f_{1} \varphi  \, dx ~ ~ +  \dots + \int_{A_{M}} f_{M}\varphi  \, dx 
\end{align}
$$
Now let $X_{|i}$ be a random variable that has pdf of $X$ in cell $A_{i}$ and $0$ everywhere else. Then
$$
\begin{align}
\dots &=  \mathbb{E}_{X_{|1}}\left[ f_{1} \right] ~ ~ + \dots +  \mathbb{E}_{X_{|M}}\left[ f_{M} \right] 
\end{align}
$$
and, since the expectation over a constant is just that constant, we'd have
$$
\begin{align}
\dots &= f_{1} + \dots + f_{M}
\end{align}
$$
This seems weird since the expectation $\mathbb{E}_{X}\left[ f(X) \right]$ would then be the *sum* of the individual values whereas intuitively I'd expect it to be more like a weighted mean.

Comment: You didn't properly normalize the pdf of $X_{|i}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @J. Delaney noticed you didn't normalize it properly.

$$
\Pr(X \in A_i) = \int_{A_i} p(x) dx
$$

so

$$
\int_{A_i} f(x) p(x) dx
$$

*is not* the expected value as it integrates over just a part of the support for $x$. So you *are not* summing the expected values. The integration [is correct](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/ap-calculus-ab/ab-integration-new/ab-6-8c/v/definite-integrals-of-piecewise-functions), you just misunderstood the integrals over the $A_i$ subsets as expected values.

If you had [conditional expectations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_expectation)

$$
E[f(X) | X \in A_i] = \int f(x) \frac{P(X = x, X \in A_i)}{P(X \in A_i)} dx
$$

then indeed you would have to use the weighted average of those with the weights equal to $P(X \in A_i)$ to cancel the denominator above (see also the [law of total expectation](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_expectation)).

Comment: Thank you. Will look at this in more detail later. In principle, could I decompose the expectation over X into conditional expectations over the Ai's?

Comment: Oh yeah well, I suppose that's pretty much the special case of the [law of total expectation](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_expectation).

Comment: @ngmir yes, indeed.